# Duplicating any type in a function in swift

Tags: swift

so I made a func called duplicate that essentially takes any type and duplicates it however many times you want. It works flawlessly in swift playgrounds.

I am here to find out if there is a different/easier way to do what I am doing. The reason I ask is because I am taking the swift course on teamtreehouse.com. and supposedly this code does not work. So there must be a better way with less code or something to do the exact same thing I've done. Here is my code.

```
func duplicate<T>(_ item: T,_ numberOfItems: Int) -> Array<T> {
    var items = numberOfItems
    var newArray: [T] = []
    while( items > 0){
        newArray.append(item)
        items = items - 1
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: This might be better suited in another question, but why is it that numberOfItems is declared as a let constant? It won't allow me to do "numberOfItems = numberOfItems -1" That gives me an error saying that numberOfItems is a let constant.

Comment: See the [In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID173) section of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) for a discussion about function parameters. The 1st paragraph gives a good summary.

Comment: i check your code and it's work. Could you explain where is the problem?

Comment: I need someone to tell me why this is a bad question.

Comment: And why the answers deserve upvotes but my question deserves downvotes

Comment: @Contro I didn't down vote but it's probably because no one understands what you are asking. Two people posted answers and you replied to both that it wasn't what you were asking. Since no one knows what you are asking, your question is getting some down votes. I suggest you [edit] your question and provide more specific details about what you want.

Comment: You asked *"if there is a different/easier way to do what I am doing"*, and if people show you various easier ways then you [accuse them of "answer to farm points"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475892/duplicating-any-type-in-a-function-in-swift#comment72092711_42476065) ...

Answer (score 1):

`Array` already has this built in, hard to get shorter than that:

```
let arr1 = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 1000)
let arr2 = [String](repeating: "hello", count: 20)
```

If you want some customization of the elements, use `map`:

```
let arr3 = (0..<10).map { i -> String in
    return i % 2 == 0 ? "hello" : "world"
}
```

If you still insist on writing your own loop:

```
func duplicate<T>(_ item: T,_ numberOfItems: Int) -> [T] {
    guard numberOfItems > 0 else { return [T]() }

    var newArray = [T]()
    for _ in 0..<numberOfItems {
        newArray.append(item)
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: A better question would be, How could I clean up this code. not what's the swift function that does this already.

Answer (score 1):

### Array init method

```
func duplicate<T>(_ item: T,_ numberOfItems: Int) -> [T] {
    return [T](repeating: item, count: numberOfItems)
}
```

### Range with map

```
func duplicate<T>(_ item: T,_ numberOfItems: Int) -> [T] {
    return (0..<numberOfItems).map { _ in item }
}
```

### Range with forEach and append

```
func duplicate<T>(_ item: T,_ numberOfItems: Int) -> [T] {
    var newArray = [T]()
    (0..<numberOfItems).forEach { _ in newArray.append(item) }
    return newArray 
}
```

### While loop and append

```
func duplicate<T>(_ item: T,_ numberOfItems: Int) -> [T] {
    var numberOfItems = numberOfItems
    var newArray = [T]()
    while(numberOfItems > 0) {
        newArray.append(item)
        numberOfItems -= 1
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: this is just using the array function in my function very redundant. Imagine the swift developers forgot to implement this into the array class. What would you do? just give up because you don't know how? No you'd do what I do above

Comment: I'm convinced a lot of people on here just read three words of the question then answer to farm points, then 5 other people will re-state what the first person said.

Comment: @Contro Imagine the swift developer's forgot to implement `append` into the array class. What would you do? 
Language provides us with such functionality, which should be used. Do not reinvent the wheel again

Comment: but if you don't understand how the wheel works then you can't invent things better or similar. I'd like to know how a function works not just what it does. So that if i have a very specific problem that requires a different implementation of the function then I have a base understanding of the function.